# In Azure Test Plans, is there a way to view all test documents in one place?

Tags: azure-test

My team uses **manual** execution with Azure Test Plans test cases.

When the manual test execution is complete in the "Execute" tab, they attach the test evidence (screen shots, etc.) in the "Run" attachments.

Is there a place to view all attached test evidence for a Test Suite without having to go into the *Execute > Test Case > Test Case Results > Run > Result attachments*?

Thanks,
Richard